# How to pass multiple arguments while using multiprocessing.Pool(10).map() for multiple image downloading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a method to download images using `requests` and `PIL`.

```
def load_save_image_from_url(url,OUT_DIR,img_name,resize=False,resize_shape=(224,224)):
    '''
    Save Images to disc present at a URL. Images are saved in RGB  format.
    args:
        url: {str} URL string where image is present
        OUT_DIR: {str} Path to the output directory where you want to store the image
        img_name: {str} Name of image
        resize: {bool} Whether to resize image or not. {default: True}
        resize_shape: {tuple} shape of the resize image {default: (224,224)}
    '''
    pass # download process
```

I want to use mutithreading/multiprocessing to it. **I have made this function specifically so that I don't to face certain problems and can not change the arguments passed or the functionality**. How can I pass multiple arguments to the `map`? I tried using the `partial` but it gives me an error as:

```
  File "/home/deshwal/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 669, in __init__
    if chunksize <= 0:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

```
urls = df.iloc[:10,0].tolist()
names = [str(i) for i in range(len(urls))]
p1 = Pool(10)
p1.map(partial(load_save_image_from_url,OUT_DIR=DIR,resize=resize,resize_shape=resize_shape), urls,names)
```

Can I even do this?

Comment: "I tried using the partial but it gives me an error." Which error?

Comment: `File "/home/deshwal/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 669, in __init__
    if chunksize <= 0:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`. I have also updated the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python multiprocessing paramiko ssh connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525896/python-multiprocessing-paramiko-ssh-connections)

Comment: so partial won't do ant good?

Comment: Your issue is trying to ``map`` *both* ``urls`` and ``names``, not ``partial``. ``Pool.map`` supports only *one* iterable of arguments, so either ``urls`` or ``names``

Comment: Oh okay. So I need to think of a way. I need to modify the whole implementation then.